# Python for-loop, range counter

Tags: python, for-loop, counter

I have made a program that prints the each date of year. Is it possible to add a counter that will allow to limit the printable dates? I would print for example every 7 days. Thanks for any advice. 
The original code below.

```
def main():

    for month in range(1, 13):
        daymax = 32
        if month == 2:
            daymax = 29
        elif month == 4:
            daymax = 31
        elif month == 6:
            daymax = 31
        elif month == 9:
            daymax = 31
        elif month == 11:
            daymax = 31

        for day in range(1, daymax):
            print(day,".", month,".", sep="")


main()
```

Comment: Have a look at the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#module-datetime) module.

Comment: This is a really strong candidate for datetimes and timedeltas.  You'll get all sorts of benefits like leap-year support, time zones, etc.

Comment: Also, have a look at the [`calendar` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html).

Comment: `daymax = 29` is only for leap years.

Answer (score 0):

Just use another counter variable, and check if it's a multiple of `7`.

```
def main():
    counter = 0
    for month in range(1, 13):
        daymax = 32
        if month == 2:
            daymax = 29
        elif month == 4:
            daymax = 31
        elif month == 6:
            daymax = 31
        elif month == 9:
            daymax = 31
        elif month == 11:
            daymax = 31

        for day in range(1, daymax):
            if counter % 7 == 0:
                print(day,".", month,".", sep="")
            counter += 1
```

Comment: @DeepSpace That doesn't work because months aren't a multiple of 7 days.

Comment: 7 days after January 28 is Feb 4, but that will print Feb 1.

Comment: Indeed..........

Comment: @DeepSpace: `counter` is the *ordinal day in the year*, not the ordinal day in the month.

Comment: Than you! This works, but I have still a little problem:
Now printing begins on the first day of the month. The first day should be 3.1 and then every 7 days printing.

Comment: Hey again, I got this resolved. Thank you everybody!

Comment: @Hello Why should the first day be 3.1 instead of 1.1?

Answer (score 0):

```
if day % 7 == 0
```

that should work. Try it.